# Will (un)installing packages on a liveUSB (Try Ubuntu) affect the installation?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, persistence

I use a live USB with Ubuntu 14.04 and persistence to boot various computers, but I was wondering if installing Chrome, removing Firefox, etc. will affect the install to HDD should I use it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Anything you delete just is no longer available to access in that session. Anything you install goes to your RAM. You should be perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm using persistence, though. Chrome stays installed after reboot, as Firefox remains uninstalled.

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to install and uninstall something or know if it is safe. Because it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

The package manager from your Ubuntu live system will not affect the hard disk of the computer it runs on¹.

¹ Unless you jump through additional hoops, but you would know if you did.